# How to use DeepSort model (TF 1.x) in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.x

I have a model in Tensorflow 1.x of the famous state-of-the-art object tracking algorithm [DeepSort](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort). What I need is to export this model ([here in .pb format](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m2ebLHB2JThZC8vWGDYEKGsevLssSkjo), from the official deepsort repository, made for tensorflow 1.x) to use it in Tensorflow Serving (with tensorflow 2.x).

In order to do this, I need a SavedModel Format. A SavedModel directory has the following structure:

```
assets/
variables/
    variables.data-00000-of-00001
    variables.index
saved_model.pb
```

How can I have the variables contents from the *mars-small128.pb* file founded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m2ebLHB2JThZC8vWGDYEKGsevLssSkjo)?
How can I obtain this SavedModel structure? (I think that for *saved_model.pb* I can easily rename the *mars-small128.pb* file...)

I tried to load the model and save it again with Tensorflow 2 / Keras, withous success.

Thanks for any hint.